# Android HttpURLConnection AndroidRuntime error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

Problems are solved. The cause is that I forgot to give Internet permission to the application.

The basic function I want to implement is that

1. get a URL and connect to a remote server
2. get results from remote server and show the results on TextView

I use a asynctask to load results from remote server. However, I have been debugging the following codes for hours, and still get no clue where goes wrong. Can anyone help me out?

```
private class ReportLocationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                return reportLoc(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
            } 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            mActivityIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mReport.setText(result);
        }
    }

    private String reportLoc(String urlstring) throws IOException{

        URL url = new URL(urlstring);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



        try{
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
        String read = br.readLine();

        while(read != null) {
            //System.out.println(read);
            sb.append(read);
            read =br.readLine();

        }

        return sb.toString();
        }
        finally {
            conn.disconnect();
            }

    }
```

Comment: What is the error? post your logcat trace

Comment: Share your logcat results.. What exactly is the error?

Comment: Problems are solved. The cause is that I forgot to give Internet permission to the application. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't specified a request method. i assume you want to GET the results from the server.

```
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   conn.setReadTimeout(10000); // millis
   conn.setConnectTimeout(15000); // millis
   conn.setDoOutput(true);

   conn.connect();
   int response = conn.getResponseCode();
   if (response == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
       .....
```